# Can I use Jasmine to spy on jQuery.$?

Tags: jquery, jasmine

I would like to know if I can spy on the $ function in jQuery using Jasmine.

This is the code I want to test.

```
var Wrapper = Wrapper || {};
Wrapper.Controls = {};
/**
 * Use an anonymous function to initialize all JavaScript
 */

(function($) {
    Wrapper.Controls.Utils = function() {
        var external = {
            showHide : function(namespace, controlNameStem){
                var stem = namespace + controlNameStem;
                $(stem  + 'Controller').click();
            }
        };
        return external;
    };
    return Wrapper.Controls.Utils;
}(Wrapper.jQuery));
```

Wrapper.jQuery is in a separate file which is preloaded by Jasmine before loading Wrapper. It contains a stub jQuery which is defined like this

```
var aliasjQuery = {};

var Wrapper = Wrapper || {};
Wrapper.jQuery = aliasjQuery;
```

This means that when Wrapper is initialised, aliasjQuery is the object passed into the anonymous function as Wrapper.jQuery

My Jasmine test spec looks like this:

```
describe("form control utils", function(){

var controlUtils = Wrapper.Controls.Utils();
var namespace = 'pluto_namespace';
var controlName = 'dualNationality';


it("showHide fires click event on controlNameController", function(){
    var control = { click : function(){}}; 
    spyOn(aliasjQuery, '$').andReturn(control);
    spyOn(control, 'click');
    controlUtils.showHide(namespace, controlName);
    expect(control.click).toHaveBeenCalled();
});



});
```

I welcome any comments, even those along the lines of "why on earth do you want to do that?" and alternative solutions as I think I've spent too long staring at this.

Comment: Just a note `$(selector).click()` does not add a click event, it triggers a click event. To add one you have to pass in a handler as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, the real code will add a click event but for now I hope this illustrates the problem OK.

Comment: Your sample program is just confusing to me because it's not doing what you're saying it's doing for that and at no point do I see you actually capture a reference to jQuery. While this is just being picky I can't take your code and use it anywhere to test it without fixing these problems on my end.

Comment: I have edited the question regarding the Jasmine setup, hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this

```
var aliasjQuery = {};
```

I can create a spy function like so

```
var aliasjQuery = jasmine.createSpy();
```

and then have it return the control stub like this

```
aliasjQuery.and.returnValue(control);
```

so then I can do this

```
expect(aliasjQuery).toHaveBeenCalledWith('pluto_namespacedualNationality');
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `spyOn(window, "$")` already?

Comment: What is $ in the context of window? I am passing jQuery into my Wrapper object (which I need to do to avoid jQuery version conflicts in a portlet app) so there is no global $.

Comment: What I can do, for example, is spyOn($,"getJSON"), and that works fine. But I want to spy on the $ so that I can mock $(stem  + 'Controller').

Comment: spyOn(window, "$") gives me this: function ( selector, context ) { // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced' return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery ); }() method does not exist

Comment: Does anyone know how to spy $('.selector') ?

Comment: In that case you'd have to replace `$` with a fake that returns a spy when passed the argument. It's slightly more involved, unfortunately.